# SQL find where two tables does not match (combined key)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

```
Table: user_has_academy_team
Columns:
user_id int(11) PK
academy_team_id int(11) PK
timestamp   datetime
```

---

```
Table: user_has_academy_module
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
user_id int(11)
module_id   int(11)
academy_team_id int(11)
academy_id  int(11)
sort_number int(11)
is_complete int(11)
score_to_pass   int(11)
is_open int(11)
deadline    datetime
module_version_id   int(11)
waiting_approval    int(11)
```

---

I wish to find all the records in the table `user_has_academy_module` where `academy_team_id` and `user_id` does not match in `user_has_academy_team`

Comment: please can you share sample data to work on

Comment: Any tutorial about joins answers this basic question. Also your requirements aren't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `NOT IN` (or `NOT EXISTS`) clause: records from one table that have no match in another:

```
select * 
from user_has_academy_module
where (user_id, academy_team_id) not in 
  (select user_id, academy_team_id from user_has_academy_team);
```

In a comment to another answer you say you want to delete those records from user_has_academy_module, which is about the same query, only with `delete` instead of `select`:

```
delete 
from user_has_academy_module
where (user_id, academy_team_id) not in 
  (select user_id, academy_team_id from user_has_academy_team);
```

Comment: While a good answer, do keep in mind that mysql is notoriously slow at subqueries and also almost any RDBMS is very slow at NOT IN type of queries, so as your table grows .....

Comment: @e4c5: I didn't know that MySQL was still slow on `NOT IN`. As a not-in query can be re-written with an anti-join and execute faster as you say, why doesn't the optimizer do just that internally? Seems about time they fix this. I've never seen issues with `NOT IN` in Oracle, and I doubt I would see them in PostgreSQL or SQL Server. But you may be right that there are several DBMS out there dealing better with joins then with set operations still.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* FROM user_has_academy_team a
LEFT JOIN user_has_academy_module b 
ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.academy_team_id = academy_team_id
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL or b.academy_team_id IS NULL
```

Should give you the result (I believe, since you haven't posted sample and expected). However I feel that your table structure leaves much to be desired. If you had a auto_increment primary key on your user user_has_academy_team table instead of the composite primary key, and referred that in your other table, life would be a lot easier.

Comment: Same comment as to stravanato's answer: When using a trick (the anti-join pattern) you should at least explain how it works, why you are using it and why you are recommending it over the straight-forward `not exists`/`not in` approach. Moreover I disagree concerning the primary key. Working with composite natural keys is often more intuitive and easier than working with technical IDs. (This is especially true for big databases with much hierarchy.)

Comment: Do refer to my comment on your own answer. in mysql, the straightfoward way is actually the JOIN and the use of the primary key I have described here is a very standard pattern.

Comment: No I refer to your answer :-) The straight-forward way in SQL is working with `exists` and `in` as SQL tries to follow natural langauge in a way. (You want to find records where the pair doesn't *exist* in ... or the pair is not *in* the set of ...) An anti-join works and is a valid defense against a bad optimizer, but it's not the approach we'd describe with natural language.

Comment: I suggest that you look up the thousands of questions here asking why is my subquery so slow and their answers.

Comment: Maybe I am spoiled by Oracle which let's me say *what* data I want and not how I want the DBMS to best achieve this - which is actually what an RDBMS is supposed to do and how SQL is designed :-)

Comment: well, yes you seem to be spoiled! Though mysql is owned by oracle believe me it's a very poor relation.

Comment: I would have post this answer. Left JOIN + where columns from on-clause are NULL seems to be the standard approach in MySQL. I find it rather intuitive on a second note.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.* FROM user_has_academy_module AS m
  LEFT JOIN user_has_academy_team as t
    ON m.user_id = t.user_id
    AND m.academy_team_id = t.academy_team_id 
WHERE t.user_id IS NULL
```

That's how it works: you try to join 2 tables on one ore more fields, when the fields of the second table are NULL you know that the tables don't match on those fields.

Comment: This worked is there a way to also delete all the records in user_has_academy_module where the above match?

Comment: @stravanato: When using a trick (the anti-join pattern) you should at least explain how it works, why you are using it and why you are recommending it over the straight-forward `not exists`/`not in` approach.